# Result reshuffling during instruction selection

Tags: tuples, llvm, llvm-ir, machine-instruction, multiple-return-values

In an LLVM backend, during instruction selection, my input looks something like this:

```
t17: i16,ch = load t16:1, t2, undef:i16
```

I'd like to select an opcode that has some extra result as well, i.e. replace the above with something like

```
t17: i16, _: i16, ch = LDW t2, undef:i16
```

Of course, if I just try to replace the `load` with this `LDW`, it fails because the return types are not the same:

```
llc: lib/CodeGen/SelectionDAG/SelectionDAG.cpp:6525: 
void llvm::SelectionDAG::ReplaceAllUsesWith(llvm::SDNode*, llvm::SDNode*): 
Assertion `(!From->hasAnyUseOfValue(i) || From->getValueType(i) == To->getValueType(i)) && 
"Cannot use this version of ReplaceAllUsesWith!"' failed.
```

That's because for `i == 1`, `From->getValueType(i)` is `ch`, and `To->getValueType(i)` is `i16`.

My question is, how do I re-shuffle the tuple `(x: i16, y: i16, ch)` into `(x : i16, ch)` during instruction selection? I.e. how would I do something like

```
t17 : i16, ch = project [0, 2] (LDW t2, undef:i16)
```

where `project [0, 2]` would be some magic tuple-reshuffling pseudo-instruction that just takes care of dropping coordinate 1?

**EDIT: Found what seemed like a possible solution, but still doesn't work**

I found that there's a `MERGE_VALUES` node type which should make what I'm trying to do possible, since it allows taking some inputs and packing them into a multi-value output. So I tried

```
SDNode* LDW = CurDAG->getMachineNode(
  AVR::LDWRdPtr, SDLoc(N), VT, PtrVT, MVT::Other,
  LD->getBasePtr(), LD->getChain());
SDValue Unpack[] = { SDValue(LDW, 0), SDValue(LDW, 2) };
SDNode* NN = CurDAG->getMergeValues(Unpack, SDLoc(N)).getNode();

ReplaceNode(N, NN);
```

If I run instruction selection with `--debug`, this looks very promising, since it turns this:

```
SelectionDAG has 16 nodes:
  t0: ch = EntryToken
    t2: i16,ch = CopyFromReg t0, Register:i16 %vreg0
  t5: i16,ch = load<LD2[%v25](align=1)(dereferenceable)> t0, t2, undef:i16
    t9: ch,glue = callseq_start t5:1, TargetConstant:i16<0>
  t11: ch,glue = CopyToReg t9, Register:i16 %R25R24, t5
  t13: ch,glue = CALL t11, TargetGlobalAddress:i16<i8 (i16)* @read_ram> 0, Register:i16 %R25R24, RegisterMask:Untyped, t11:1
  t14: ch,glue = callseq_end t13, TargetConstant:i16<0>, TargetConstant:i16<0>, t13:1
    t16: i8,ch,glue = CopyFromReg t14, Register:i8 %R24, t14:1
  t17: ch = RET_FLAG t16:1
```

into this:

```
SelectionDAG has 16 nodes:
  t0: ch = EntryToken
    t9: i16,ch,glue = ADJCALLSTACKDOWN TargetConstant:i16<0>, t19:1
  t11: ch,glue = CopyToReg t9:1, Register:i16 %R25R24, t19
  t13: ch,glue = CALLk TargetGlobalAddress:i16<i8 (i16)* @read_ram> 0, Register:i16 %R25R24, RegisterMask:Untyped, t11, t11:1
  t14: i16,ch,glue = ADJCALLSTACKUP TargetConstant:i16<0>, TargetConstant:i16<0>, t13, t13:1
    t2: i16,ch = CopyFromReg t0, Register:i16 %vreg0
  t18: i16,i16,ch = LDWRdPtr t2, t0
  t19: i16,ch = merge_values t18, t18:2
    t16: i8,ch,glue = CopyFromReg t14:1, Register:i8 %R24, t14:2
  t17: ch = RET t16:1
```

which looks fine to me: `t18,_,ch` is where we store the result of `LDW`, then `t19,ch` unpacks it.

However, this later trips up instruction scheduling:

```
llc: CodeGen/SelectionDAG/InstrEmitter.cpp:305: 
unsigned int llvm::InstrEmitter::getVR(llvm::SDValue, llvm::DenseMap<llvm::SDValue, unsigned int>&): 
Assertion `I != VRBaseMap.end() && "Node emitted out of order - late"' failed.

#9 0x0000000001a7eae8 llvm::InstrEmitter::getVR(llvm::SDValue, llvm::DenseMap<llvm::SDValue, unsigned int, llvm::DenseMapInfo<llvm::SDValue>, llvm::detail::DenseMapPair<llvm::SDValue, unsigned int> >&) CodeGen/SelectionDAG/InstrEmitter.cpp:305:0
#10 0x0000000001a819c2 llvm::InstrEmitter::EmitSpecialNode(llvm::SDNode*, bool, bool, llvm::DenseMap<llvm::SDValue, unsigned int, llvm::DenseMapInfo<llvm::SDValue>, llvm::detail::DenseMapPair<llvm::SDValue, unsigned int> >&) CodeGen/SelectionDAG/InstrEmitter.cpp:928:0
#11 0x0000000001971c9c llvm::InstrEmitter::EmitNode(llvm::SDNode*, bool, bool, llvm::DenseMap<llvm::SDValue, unsigned int, llvm::DenseMapInfo<llvm::SDValue>, llvm::detail::DenseMapPair<llvm::SDValue, unsigned int> >&) CodeGen/SelectionDAG/InstrEmitter.h:124:0
#12 0x0000000001988bdb llvm::ScheduleDAGSDNodes::EmitSchedule(llvm::MachineInstrBundleIterator<llvm::MachineInstr, false>&) CodeGen/SelectionDAG/ScheduleDAGSDNodes.cpp:841:0
#13 0x0000000001a33cdc llvm::SelectionDAGISel::CodeGenAndEmitDAG() CodeGen/SelectionDAG/SelectionDAGISel.cpp:890:0
```

Comment: Actually, in the line `t19: i16,ch = merge_values t18, t18:2`, shouldn't that be `t19: i16,ch = merge_values t18, ch`? What does that `t18:2` mean?